# Lagom persistent read side and model evolution

Tags: persistence, cqrs, lagom

To learn lagom i created a simple application with some simple persistent entities and a persistent read side (as per the official documentation, using cassandra)

The official doc contains a [section about model evolution](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/latest/scala/Serialization.html#Schema-Evolution), describing how to change the model. However, there is no mention of evolution when it comes to the read side.

Assuming i have an entity called `Item`, with an `ID` and a `name`, and the read side creates a table like `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (id TEXT, name TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (id))`

I now want to change the item to include a description. This is trivial for the persistent entity, but the read side has to be changed as well.

I can see several approaches to (maybe) achieve that:

1. use a model evolution tool like liquibase or [play evolutions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Evolutions) to change the read side tables.
2. somehow include `update table` statements in `createTables` that migrate the model
3. create additional tables containing the additional information, and keep the old tables without modifications

Which approach would be the most fitting? Is there something better?

Comment: The read side doesn't need to change if it doesn't need the description.

Comment: yes of course, it is just an example to illustrate what i want to do, which is changing the read side

Comment: The point is that you _shouldn't_ be changing the read-side. If your API changes, that's a new version of the service.

Comment: In fact, this exact reason is why microservices exist: if your DB schema evolves, no one should be perturbed.

Comment: adding a description would definitely change the API and be a new version of the service. It introduces a new feature to the Item

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new table and dropping the old table is an option too IMHO.
It is simple as modifying your "create table" command ("create table mytable_v2 ..." and "drop table mytable...") and changing the offset name and modifying your event handlers.

```
override def buildHandler( ): ReadSideProcessor.ReadSideHandler[MyEvent] = {
      readSide.builder[MyEvent]("myOffset") // change it to "myOffset_v2"
      ...
}
```

This results in all events to be replayed and your read side table to be reconstructed from the scratch. This may not be an option if the current table is really huge as the recostruction may last very long time.

Regarding what @erip says I see perfectly normal adding a new column to your read side table. Suppose there are lots of records in this table with list of all entities and you want to retrieve a list of entities based on some criteria so you need some columns to be included in the where clause. Retrieving list of all entities and asking each of them if it complies with the criteria is not an option at all - it could be very unefficient as it needs more time, memory and network usage.

Answer (score 0):

The point of a read-side is to materialize views from entity state changes from your service's event stream in your service. In this respect, you as the service controller can decide what is important for your subscribers to know about. This is handled by creating read-sides with an anti-corruption layer (or ACL).

Typically your subscribers will subscribe to API events which should experience no evolution. Your internal events (or impl events) *will* likely need to evolve; because of this, there should be a transformation from the impl to the API.

This is why it's very important to consider your domain very carefully before design: you really need to nail down what subscribers will need to know about. In the case of a description, it strikes me as unlikely that subscribers will need (or want!) to know about that.

Comment: I thought that the the point of the read side is to provide specific read access to the entities, is that wrong? The docs seem to publish events using the already existing events of the event sourcing. I also don't see how changing a description is something that a subscriber won't have to know about.

Comment: A read-side can be both local or remote. In either case, it's supposed to materialize aggregates in a separate entity than event store. It should _not_ be a substitute for `SELECT * FROM XYZ`.

Comment: @Simiil What would your subscriber be doing with a description?

Comment: Show it on a user interface, for example.

Comment: Send a GET request to the service. I think your question is a bit confusing. Are you asking about a local read-side? Or a remote read-side? Local read-sides should be fine to change willy nilly since nothing depends on it.

Comment: that is exactly what i'm doing, but as soon as it gets complex than retrieving the description from one item, i have to query the read side for the data. Sorry for the confusion, I'm just learning the framework and i am a bit confused myself

Comment: if you're trying to do something like `getAll`, you'll have a read-side which maintains the set of Ids of items your service is responsible for, then issue a GET for each of the Ids your read-side has accumulated.